# Estimates of the variation of the stress-energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given a realistic stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, what would be a good estimation of the upper bound for its first derivative? That is,

\begin{equation}
K_{\mu\nu\sigma} = \sup_x \| \partial_\sigma T_{\mu\nu}(x) \|
\end{equation}

where $K$ is the Lipschitz constant of the stress-energy tensor. Obviously given the appropriate initial conditions, $K$ can be as large as wanted, but for realistic matter, I'm not sure what such a constant could be. I can think of a few estimates for energy density, but its variation is another story.

To keep things not too thorny, let's ignore any potential issue with quantum theory : if quantum effects are considered, we're taking the stress-energy tensor as

\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu}(x) = \langle \psi, \hat{T}_{\mu\nu} \psi \rangle
\end{equation}

Would there be a good estimate for this for let's say, ordinary matter? 
I know this may be a problem due to coordinate changes, but let's assume we're considering whatever matter we're looking into at rest for the purpose of looking there (ie if we're looking at the boundary of a proton, the proton is at rest).

Comment: Perhaps relevant : https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/128/11004

Comment: The question seems a bit too broad. What is “ordinary matter”? Shockwaves in quark-gluon plasma from heavy ion collisions? Gluon fluxtubes in hadron jets? (These are examples that should produce large gradients of SE tensor). Such systems  have simple (-ish) descriptions via gravity duals that tolerably agree with experiments.